# "Gentillement" or "Gentiment" ?

Tags: sens, choix-de-mot, usage

I was writing a  paragraph, then I stopped when I tried to write this word first I wrote **"gentiment"** then I felt that it can be wrong because the word is **"gentil"** so it must be **"gentillement"** I was surprised that the autocorrecteur didn't correct any, just like both of them are correct.

Comment: La seule forme correcte est « gentiment ».

Comment: J'ai trouvé cette réponse:  Gentil (ancienne forme féminine), et le suffixe -ment. Il y a eu aussi gentillement, dans lequel la formation avait été refaite sur le nouveau féminin gentille.[source1](http://www.etudes-litteraires.com/forum/topic5376-gentiment-ou-gentillement.html)
    [source2](http://www.littre.org/definition/gentiment)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Gentillement used to exist but is not used anymore; this spelling was removed from the Dictionnaire de l'Académie in 1932, according to the TLFi ([link](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/gentiment))

> Prononc. et Orth. : []. Ds Ac. 1694-1932. Gentillement (vx) : Nous commencions à causer gentillement, dimanche après-midi (FLAUB., Corresp., 1842, p. 91). Et elle expliquait cela si humblement et si gentillement que c'était plaisir de l'entendre (SAND, Pte Fad., 1849, p. 185).

The correct spelling is therefore *gentiment.*

Comment: I've never seen or heard it in the last half-century+

Answer (score 7):

Here is a good explanation from [this article](https://www.lalanguefrancaise.com/orthographe/gentillement-ou-gentiment-orthographe/):

> Règle : on écrit toujours « gentiment » : « gentillement » était une
>   forme correcte… il y a quelques siècles mais plus maintenant ! On est
>   tenté de l’écrire « gentillement » à cause de l’adjectif « gentil »
>   qui se termine par « l ». Il faut avant tout se fier à la prononciation du mot. Si « gentiment » était écrit avec les deux « l », il se prononcerait « gentiyement » ce qui n’est pas le cas. L’orthographe de « gentiment » est, pour une fois, le reflet de sa prononciation.

Answer (score 4):

According to *Le Petit Robert*, only *gentiment* is correct.